# Can I arbitrarily replace and restore the db.sqlite3 file?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I know that the file `db.sqlite3` in Django holds the entire database and the entire content within it. Is it safe to keep all the project files, the `*.py` files, the `migrations` files, but replace the `db.sqlite3` file with a different one. If both these `db.sqlite3` files work on the same database model, with the same tables, rows, columns, and everything, then if I swap out that file it should work seamlessly.

I want to copy the original `db.sqlite3` file into a different directory. Then I want to create a new `db.sqlite3` file in my project. Then I want to work with the new database file, and give it other data to test how the project would work with it. Then I want to delete the new `db.sqlite3` file, and I want to restore the old one, which I've saved into another directory.

Would that work? And how can I create a new `db.sqlite3` file, a clean state to put test data into?

Also, what if I build my project on another sever, can I copy my old `db.sqlite3` file there too, and have the database with all it's saved data restored?

Basically, the main idea of my question is: are we to treat the `db.sqlite3` file as a simple "text file" with input/output data for our program, something that is freely interchangeable?

Comment: Yes, it would work. I do that during development. > *"Also, what if I build my project on another sever, can I copy my old db.sqlite3 file there too, and have the database with all it's saved data restored?"* -- I've done that as well for a small project where I created all the data during development and later uploaded the database to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, whole sqlite database is contained in one file, so you can freely move, replace, push it with django project (althought it's not recommended) and it will work fine.

Even if you have 2 different projects with same apps, same model structure and migrations, you can swap them.

If you remove your `db.sqlite3` and want to create new one, just run `python manage.py migrate` and it will create new database and apply all migrations.

Answer (score 3):

The whole of the database lives in the .db file. You can safely copy it in either direction when there is no process running against the database. If there is a process running against the database then you might see rollback journal files or write-ahead log files in the same directory (if the database is in WAL mode) and if you leave these behind you might risk losing some pending transactions. Closing the database properly generally causes these files to disappear.